# Laravel Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUsername does not exist

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

When I'm trying to submit a form and validate it i get the following error Message:

Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateUsername does not exist.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use http\Env\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller



{
    public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('main')->plainTextToken;
        return response(compact('user', 'token'));
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validated();
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Provided username or password is incorrect'
            ], 422);
        }

        /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
        $user = Auth::user();
        $token = $user->createToken('main')->plainTextToken;
        return response(compact('user', 'token'));
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
        $user = $request->user();
        $user->currentAccessToken()->delete();
        return response('', 204);
    }
}
```

I've already used this command `composer dump-autoload` to reload the methods, however it didn't work

Heres my LoginRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|username|string|exists:users,username',
            'password' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'remember' => 'boolean'
        ];
    }
}
```

I guess somethings wrong in the username rule
Thanks for the answers guys :D

Comment: Remove the `username` rule from your `App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

post the content of your `App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest` and `App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest`. The error shows that you used a custom rule named `username` that is not defined.

Edit:
You used a custom 'username' rule that you probably did not define. Remove the rule after 'required' or define it.

```
/**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // Change this
            'username' => 'required|username|string|exists:users,username',
            // To this.
            'username' => 'required|string|exists:users,username',
            'password' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'remember' => 'boolean'
        ];
    }
```

However, if you defined the custom `username` rule, make sure you did it correctly. Example, put the following in your service provider.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('username', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        // Custom validation logic goes here
        // Return true if the validation passes, false otherwise
    });
}
```

Comment: posted it thanks for answering